# Recyclerview items don't answer for first click

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem with assigning onclicklistener to recyclerview items.
When I click the item, first click is ignored and listener doesn't run.
I mean, I have to click once, and then again to run the listener.
Once it runs, listener works well.

here is my code.

```
public class BoardFragment extends Fragment {

//recycler view ingredient
private RecyclerView recyclerView_board;
public static board_adapter mboard_adapter;
public static ArrayList<board_item> board_itemList;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager board_LayoutManager;
//recycler view ingredient end

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(fragment_board, container, false);

    //recycler view setting
    recyclerView_board = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.board_recycler);

    board_itemList = new ArrayList<board_item>();

    board_LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mboard_adapter = new board_adapter(board_itemList);
    recyclerView_board.setAdapter(mboard_adapter);
    recyclerView_board.setLayoutManager(board_LayoutManager);
    recyclerView_board.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView_board.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView_board.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    board_item item = new board_item();
    item.setName("Hello");
    board_itemList.add(item);
    mboard_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //recycler view setting end

    return v;
}

public static class board_item {
    private String name;
    private CheckBox button;
    private int state = 0;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public CheckBox getButton() {
        return this.button;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setButton(CheckBox button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

public class board_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<board_adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<board_item> temp_board_array;

    public board_adapter(ArrayList<board_item> board_itemList) {
        temp_board_array = board_itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_board, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(new board_onclick_listener());
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int itemposition = position;

        holder.board_name_text.setText(temp_board_array.get(position).getName());

        class board_button_onclick_listener implements View.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                board_item item = board_itemList.get(itemposition);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(item.getState() == 0){

                }

                else {

                }

            }

        }

        holder.board_favorite_button.setOnClickListener(new board_button_onclick_listener());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return temp_board_array.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView board_name_text;
        public CheckBox board_favorite_button;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            board_name_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.board_name);
            board_favorite_button = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.board_favorite_button);

        }
    }

    //각 아이템에 적용될 리스너
    class board_onclick_listener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            int itemposition = recyclerView_board.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
            board_item item = board_itemList.get(itemposition);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), item.getName() + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CardActivity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What listener you want to run? `board_button_onclick_listener` or `board_onclick_listener`

Comment: `board_onclick_listener`,  please